# What is the right way to use baked lightmap in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, light

I've confused how lightmap is used in Cycles to speed up rendering,

1.Is it a proper way to bake every objects its own lightmap, or bake several objects into one lightmap, what is the pros and cons?

2.When talking about UV channels, is the term UV channels equivalent to UV layout, but different from UV map, from what I know the uV map should be referring to the actual image.

3.Should I use lightmap and texture based on the same UV layout, or is it better to use different UV layout, which is your preferred way?

4.When I got my lightmap, I textured it and I can see the final results, but, the light in the scene is still active so I disabled the light in the scene, but the object becomes darker because no light in the scene, then the lightmap can not be seen without light is Embarrassing, I add an emission shader to make it visiable but problem comes, should I needs to bake another emission map in order to  see the lightmap, sorry I'm confused what is the right workflow to use lightmap in cycles?